# Scala match case return Any type instead of returned types by the match case

Tags: scala

Why does the following code returns `Any` instead of `Double` type, while all match cases return double?

```
  trait A

  case class B() extends A

  case class C() extends A

  def someMethod(o: Option[A]): Double = {
    o.map(v =>  {
      case B => 1.3
      case C => 1.2
      case others => 2.3
    }).getOrElse(0.0)

    // Expression of type Any doesn't conform to expected type Double >
  }
```

Comment: are you asking for the reason why compiler behaves this way, or asking how to work around this?

Comment: Also is that error something your IDE is claiming or compiler is throwing? The map won't compile on the more recent versions of Scala, so I find it hard to believe it even got to type checking. If it is the former, and especially if you are using intelliJ, IDEs do that when they can't compile

Comment: Your code have a couple of typos, as well as some unnecessary code. In any case, [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/MdLCos2HQqm8LgIQLmdr6g/2) compiles and behaves as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplifying the problem, consider the following invalid syntax

```
val f: String => Double = x => { case v => 3.14 }
```

This does not compile because expression containing `cases` clauses without prior `match`

`{ case v => 3.14 }`

expands to function

```
y => y match { case v => 3.14 }
```

hence `f` expands to something like

```
val f: String => Double = x => (y => y match { case v => 3.14 })
```

where we see that instead of `String => Double` we are attempting `String => (? => Double)` and we do not have enough information to infer what type should `?` be.

Hence the correct use of the syntax is

```
val f: String => Double = { case v => 3.14 }
```

where we note the absence of explicit `x =>`.

Refer to [SLS 8.5 Pattern Matching Anonymous Functions](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-matching-anonymous-functions) for precise specification.

Answer (score 3):

Following up from my comments.Fixing the code to allow map to compile...

If you want to match on types you can do something like this

```
trait A

case class B() extends A

case class C() extends A

def someMethod(o: Option[A]): Double = o.map{
     case _ : B => 1.3
     case _ : C => 1.2
     case _ => 2.3
}.getOrElse(0.0)
```

Working [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/0hxDH6GwTm21Ai0pMMt10g)

Another option if these are your final definitions is using `case objects` in which case you can do what you were doing

```
trait A

case object B extends A

 case object C extends A

 def someMethod(o: Option[A]): Double = o.map{
     case B => 1.3
     case C => 1.2
     case _ => 2.3
}.getOrElse(0.0)
```

Keep in mind that you are still limited in things you can do in pattern matching because of the type erasure